# Schema validation, how to enforce the existance of property at top level based on condition in lower level

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I'm trying to write a schema to validate a yaml file after parsing it into JSON.

Supposing that this is my .yml file with 2 top level properties, cars and garage.

cars is optional while garage is required.

However, one of garage's sub-properties is cars. If cars under garage is defined, I want the schema to make sure that cars at the top level is also defined. Otherwise, the schema is not going to be valid

```
cars:
  - BMW
  - Mercedes-Benz
  - Audi

garage:
  location: Miami
  cars:
    - BMW
    - Audi
```

My Schema:

```
{
  properties: {
    cars: {
       type: 'array',
       items: {
          type: 'string'
       }
     },
    garage: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
          location: {
            type: 'string'
           },
          cars: {
            type: 'array'
         }
    },
 required: ['garage']
}}
```

So I tried doing an if-else at the top level

```
{
  if: { properties: { garage: { cars: {type: 'array'}}}},
  then: {required:['cars']},
  properties: {
    cars: {
       type: 'array',
       items: {
          type: 'string'
       }
     },
    garage: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
          location: {
            type: 'string'
           },
          cars: {
            type: 'array'
         }
    },
 required: ['garage']
}}
```

But it seems that I'm doing it wrong or it doesn't serve that purpose.

Also doing anyOf at the top level to match sub-schemas didn't work for me..

Any help ?

Comment: FYI it would be helpful if you provided your instance in JSON also. The fact that it's in YAML and converted to JSON is irrelevant. I'm building tooling which will make sharing schemas and instances easier, in JSON and YAML =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the referential integrity constraint (together with all the other requirements) using the "JSON Extended Structure Schema" language, [JESS](https://github.com/pkoppstein/JESS).

Here is the complete JESS schema presented as a single JSON document:

```
[ "&",
  ["&",
    {"::>=": {"garage": {"location": "string", "cars": [ "string" ] } } }
  ],
  {"ifcond": { "has": "cars" },
    "then": ["&", { "forall": ".[cars]", "schema": ["string"]  } ]
  },
  {"setof": ".[garage]|.[cars][]", "subsetof": ".[cars][]"}
]
```

The first "&" introduces the conjunction of the three requirements, the last of which is the referential integrity constraint.

The [JESS repository](https://github.com/pkoppstein/JESS) has a schema conformance checker, which I used to verify your sample (expressed as JSON) against the above schema.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `if` must be a JSON Schema.
If you take the value of `if` as a JSON Schema on it's own and test the validation result of applying it to the correct location in your JSON instance, it may help you debug this type of issue.

In your `if` block, you need to put nest `cars` under `properties`, just like you've done in your main schema.

You may also want to make both garage and cars required in your `if` block.]

You cannot however define that you want the values from `garage.cars` to be included in your `cars` array.